# subConsulta select transformada a DQL

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony3, symfony, dql

Estoy utilizando `MySQL` y tengo este `select`:

```
Select 
TOP 15
Item 
DescriptionforSales
, (select  top 1 Retail from Pricelist where Pricelist.peachitemid = products.peachitemid ) as Retail "
From products where imagen=1 and active=1
```

Al convertirlo en `dql` hasta aquí no tengo problema:

```
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dql="SELECT p.ItemID, p.DescriptionforSales
              FROM BackendBundle:Products p";
              $query=$em->createQuery($dql);

        $query=$em->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setMaxResults(15);
```

El problema es al colocar la subconsulta. Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las entidades no tenian relacion por esta raz{on se define la consulta de otra forma pero el resultado es lo que se necesita de esta forma:

```
SELECT p
FROM BackendBundle:Products p
JOIN BackendBundle:Pricelist pl
WITH p.peachitemid =  pl.peachitemid
WHERE p.hasimages =  1
Order by p.bestseller desc
```

Saludos